# Make tikz picture floating

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning

I'm inserting a tikz picture in my section headings with `\titleformat` (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15712/calculating-position-in-tikz)) and I would like it to not affect the spaces in the headings. Right now, what I do is that I compensate the introduction of the picture with a negative vspace:

```
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}[display]
  {\newpage\secstyle} % format
  {\large\makedate{\thesection}~\chaphead} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-5mm}\filcenter\textls[-50]} %before
  [\monthtab{\chaphead}{\arabic{chapter}}\vspace{-1.2cm}] % after
```

`\monthtab` is the macro that inserts the picture to the right of the page. Is there a way to make it so that the picture inserted by `\monthtab` does not affect the spacing at all, making it float in the page?

Here are some examples. First, a section without a tab:

[image: section without a tab]

Then, a section with a tab and nothing to prevent the vertical space:

[image: section with a tab, no vspace]

Finally, when I add a negative `\vspace` to fix it (call that the target):

[image: section with a tab and vspace]

And here is a "minimal" example to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass[paper=6.14in:9.21in,pagesize=pdftex,10pt,DIV=15]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\monthtab}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3*{#2}cm,xshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north east) {
      \tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=white,top color=gray!50,shading angle=-90] 
        (0,0) rectangle (1cm,3cm) node[rotate=90,pos=0.5] {\Large\scshape #1};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\secstyle}{\scshape\Huge}

% Tune section headings
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}[display]
  {\newpage\secstyle} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-5mm}\filcenter\textls[-35]} %before
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}[display]
  {\newpage\secstyle} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-5mm}\filcenter\textls[-50]} %before
  [\monthtab{Chapname}{\arabic{chapter}}] % after
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*}{*-2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Janvier}
\section{This is a test section}

\begin{center}
Some text here
\end{center}

\section{This is another section}

\begin{center}
Some text here
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm having a hard time making it shorter than this... Compare pages 2 and 3:

- on page 2, the text almost touches the title;
- on page 3, the tab to the right adds a space after the title.

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Matthew: I added 3 examples to illustrate.

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with the `tikzpicture` (as an `overlay` picture takes no space). The problem seems to be that titlesec adds an (empty) paragraph if the optional argument is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of anything nontrivial in the optional *after* parameter of `\titleformat` seems to cause `titlesec` to insert a new line. I don't know how to avoid that, but a simple `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` should undo the effect.

```
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}[display]
  {\newpage\secstyle} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-5mm}\filcenter\textls[-50]} %before
  [\monthtab{Chapname}{\arabic{chapter}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}] % after
```

Alternatively, you can add the `\monthtab` to the *before* argument:

```
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}[display]
  {\newpage\secstyle} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-5mm}\monthtab{Chapname}{\arabic{chapter}}%
   \filcenter\textls[-50]}
```

---

The current `\monthtab` macro contains two uncommented newlines, both of which add a space to the text. To avoid this, add a comment character at the end of the line, like

```
\newcommand{\monthtab}[2]{% <--- comment here
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[yshift={ -3*(mod(#2-1,6)+1)*1cm},xshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north east) {
      \tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=white,top color=gray!50,shading angle=-90] 
        (0,0) rectangle (1cm,3cm) node[rotate=90,pos=0.5] {\Large\scshape #1};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- comment here
}
```

Comment: I had tried using `\monthtab` in the *before* argument already. It doesn't cause the vertical space issue, but it forces the text to cut earlier on long lines, which is a problem on some of my pages where section names are long. All in all, I think your solution of using `-\baselineskip` is the cleanest, as it prevents me from *guessing* the height of the added line. Thank you.

Comment: @Raphink: It works for me: http://i.imgur.com/Uz7s5.png. Note that the `\vspace` is before `\monthtab` (I think the problem is that `tikzpicture` always leaves vertical mode (i.e. starts a paragraph); thus the `\vspace` must be before it).

Comment: When I call `\monthtab` from *before* with the long title I have above (Toutes les promesses de Dieu), then the last word (Dieu) ends up on a second line. This doesn't happen when I use it in the *after* parameter.

Comment: @Raphink: Sorry, I misunderstood. See the extended answer for why this happens and how to solve the problem.

Comment: 3 newlines even in my complete code (since the one in my example was stripped to make it shorter). Thanks, that works great, and I could now get rid of the *after* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Placing it in `\rlap{...}` or `\llap{...}` would make it not take any official space. It simply laps to the right or left. However, this might overprint some of the following text.

---

#### Update

Ok, now with your examples I can see what's the problem is. The `\rlap` and `\llap` only take care about the horizontal space, not the vertical one. You would need the vertical versions for it. However, because you are using `tikz` you can do that using its commands instead. Simply make sure, that the picture has no vertical space, at best also no horizontal one.

Try to add `\useasboundingbox (0,0);` at the beginning of the picture where `(0,0)` here stands for the center of it. This way the picture has a size of 0 in both directions and the drawing material simply laps over in all directions.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, it doesn't seem to work. Maybe the fact of calling `[]%after` in `\titleformat` already allocates a vertical space, even if the contents use `\rlap` or `\llap`?

Comment: @Raphink: Does it make no difference at all?

Comment: @Martin: Not a difference that my eyes can see.

Comment: @Raphink: See my updated answer.

Comment: @Martin: you mean `useasboundingbox`, not `useasboudingbox` I guess. I've put it between the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\node` lines, but it doesn't fix the issue. The space is actually even bigger with `useasboundingbox`, as the paragraph in italic only begins under the bottom of the tab picture strictly now.

Comment: @Raphink: If you would provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) things would be much easier. Without it a can only guess what is going wrong.

Comment: @Martin: A `tikzpicture` with overlay always takes no space.

Comment: @Caramdir: Good idea! But you also need to define the official center, don't you?

Comment: no, the picture is absolutely positioned on the page anyway.