# tikzpicture without leaving vertical mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

It seems that the `tikzpicture` environment always leaves vertical mode, even when the `overlay` option is given (and thus the picture doesn't actually take any space). This can cause [unexpected behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/make-tikz-picture-floating).

Is there a way to prevent TeX from leaving vertical mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is not that TeX leaves vertical mode - if you capture the content into a `\vbox`, the "leave vertical mode" command is restricted locally to that box.

The problem is how TeX appends vertical boxes to each other: it does so by inserted interlineskip.

I have experimented a little bit using three `\vbox`es which are put above each other -- trying to eliminate the size of the box in the middle. I succeeded when I used `\nointerlineskip` in front of it.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Without Text:

\vbox{A vertical box}%
\vbox{A vertical box}%


\vskip3cm
With Text:

%\offinterlineskip 
\vbox{A vertical box}%
\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 0pt{%
hallo
}%
%\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
%\draw (0,0) circle(1cm);
%\end{tikzpicture}%
\vbox{A vertical box}%


\vskip3cm
With Picture instead of text (should be the same):

%\offinterlineskip 
\vbox{A vertical box}%
\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 0pt{%
\tikz \draw (0,0) circle(1cm);
}%
\vbox{A vertical box}%

\end{document}
```

The `\offinterlineskip` would disable interline skip for all boxes, whereas `\nointerlineskip` deactivates it only for the next.

I hope that this actually captures the problem (but perhaps I got it all wrong)