# Tikzpicture with overlay takes up space

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [circle, fill=red!90!black, minimum width=15em] at (current page.center) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Amazing movable type!}
\end{document}
```

The section title is moved even though the picture with overlay should take up no space. Try inputting just a section title without `tikzpicture`, and notice that there is less vertical space above section title:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Amazing movable type!}
\end{document}
```

or see illustration:

[image: Tikzpicture with overlay takes up space]

The behavior is the same with comments which should eat up spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node [circle, fill=red!90!black, minimum width=15em] at (current page.center) {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\section{Amazing movable type!}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that extra vertical space is added when:

- tikzpicture is inputted before `section` titles
- tikzpicture is inputted before `description` environment
- tikzpicture is inputted before `itemize` environment
- tikzpicture is inputted before `enumerate` environment

Tikzpicture behaves as expected with normal text. For example, this will work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, tikz}

\begin{document}
\section{Amazing movable type!}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [circle, fill=red!90!black, minimum width=15em] at (current page.center) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%but you must not leave some space here, otherwise, a single blank space is shown before text.
\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

Why is that happening and how can it be prevented? The `\useasboundingbox (0,0);` suggestion from [Make tikz picture floating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/make-tikz-picture-floating)  does not help.

### edit

Caramdir's suggestion to input`\nointerlineskip` before `tikzpicture` seems to fix vertical space issue for section titles, but descriptions and similar environments still have undesired extra vertical space. See illustration:

[image: nointerlineskip kludge]

Comment: I don't see anything in your illustration (the two lines look the same to me), but I guess what you mean is that additional vertical white space is inserted. This probably happens for the same reason that you have the comment in your last example. The `tikzpicture` does seem to always switch to horizontal mode so that the blank lines before and after are interpreted as paragraph breaks. Commenting them out should help.

Comment: As far as I know an TikZ overlay still adds itself as *whatsit* object at its original location. I had similar issues with `zref`s `\zlabel`s and Heiko Oberdiek told me that such things can't be placed into the document without disturbing the spacing. At least that's the way I understood it. However, he uses the LaTeX space hack around it, which doesn't help that much in vertical mode.

Comment: No, the space hack (`\@bsphack .. \@esphack`) doesn't work here. It actually raises an error. The same space appears when you replace the `tikzpicture` with a `\marginpar`. Also placing `tikzpicture` inside a `\vbox to 0pt{.. \vss}` doesn't help. This seems to be a tricky issue which requires someone with deep knowledge of TeX.

Comment: @Caramdir: I edited the illustration to make it more readable. Yes, vertical space is inserted. Commenting does not help -- I've also edited my example code -- vertical space is still inserted.
@Martin: The thing that puzzles me is why can the `tikzpicture` be placed before text without disturbing the spacing, but cannot be placed in front of sections and environments.

Comment: [Adding `\nointerlineskip` before the `tikzpicture`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/tikzpicture-without-leaving-vertical-mode/16276#16276) solves the problem, except at the beginning of the document (where an additional paragraph seems to be inserted somewhere).

Comment: @Caramdir: Your suggestion seems to work for section titles space issues, but not for environments. See my updated answer.

Comment: The trick with \nointerlineskip works, but not at the beginning of a page, because the space preceding the section header doesn't vanish since there's a box before it. The bad interaction with list environments is due to `\addvspace`: the list environment doesn't "see" a previous vertical space, again because of the box.

Comment: Maybe this should be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This `tikzpicture` environment must be embedded in a paragraph, for example at start or end

```
\section{Not amazing}

\begin{tikzpicture}[...]...\end{tikzpicture}%
Text of the paragraph
```

If it's put between paragraphs, it will interact badly with all spacing features. Vertical space won't disappear at page breaks, baselineskip space will be inserted, `\addvspace` won't know about a space before that environment.

It should be TikZ's job to recognize that such an overlay environment mustn't do anything to the current page and reserve it for the shipout. Even with **atbegshi** there are problems:

```
\AtBeginShipout{\begin{tikzpicture}[...]...\end{tikzpicture}}
```

causes the output to be shifted down (with an overfull vbox warning) again because the TikZ picture produces an hbox.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem. Is there any possibility to somehow allow these `overlay` `tikzpicture` between paragraphs as well? In such cases (but not all cases) the position of overlay pictures is not relevant because they draw on the page directly. So could this picture code instead be saved and reinserted at the end of the page using some at-shipout or similar hook?

Answer (score 2):

If you can make do with at most one overlay picture per page, you can use the `background` package (see also [TikZ overlay picture influences text around it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434347/tikz-overlay-picture-influences-text-around-it/435790#435790)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, showframe}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background} 

\begin{document}

\backgroundsetup{opacity=1, scale=1, angle=0, contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [circle, fill=red!90!black, minimum width=15em] at (current page.center) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\BgThispage

\section{Amazing movable type!}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can put the overlaying `tikzpicture` environments in a box of width zero:

```
\makebox[0pt][c]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

I have also found that "accidental" empty lines, created by code-structuring line breaks, can cause unwanted space added. Make sure to comment out all line endings in sensitive code areas.

Comment: This does not seem to work for the MWE in the question.