# Asking a tikz picture to render at a specific relative location and to not take any space

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, itemize

I was wondering if there is a way to get the following behavior using TikZ (overlaying text with at a location relative to the anchor point in the text)

[image]

The code would look like this:

```
Here is a list:

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}

Here's what I want:

\begin{itemize}
\item \placetext{2007,-0.3cm,0cm} One
\item \placetext{2009,-0.3cm,0cm} Two
\item \placetext{2012,-0.3cm,0cm} Three
\end{itemize}
```

where the command `\placetext{text,x_location,y_location}` should place the text `text` at the **relative** location `x_location` and `y_location` from the anchor point on the text.

I have been experimenting with the following code that I found [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/tikzpicture-with-overlay-takes-up-space) to ask LaTeX and TikZ to print text that "does not take space" with no success.

```
\makebox[0pt][c]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, overlay]
\node[draw=none,fill=none]  {Hello};\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Is this possible at all with TikZ? How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need tikz for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\placetext#1#2#3{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(#2,#3){\llap{#1}}%
\end{picture}%
}

Here's what I want:

\begin{itemize}
\item \placetext{2007}{-.5}{0}One  % Note: no space after the macro
\item \placetext{2009}{-.5}{0}Two
\item \placetext{2012}{-.5}{0}Three
\item Four
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

**Update**

If for some reason (for example, in order to apply tikz styles to the "floating" text), youn insist in using tikz, you can still use `\tikz` inside `\put`, using LaTeX `picture` environment. But there is a caveat. If you don't use any path from (0,0) to the text position, the resulting box generated by tikz would not contain (0,0) and thus will not be properly positioned. Also you have to set correctly the `baseline` of the tikz picture, in order to align it properly with the `\item` text.

Here you have a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\placetext#1#2#3{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(0,0){\llap{\tikz[baseline=(m.base)]\path (0,0)--(#2,#3) 
  node[left, fill=orange!30] (m) {#1};}}
\end{picture}%
}

\begin{document}
Here's what I want:

\begin{itemize}
\item \placetext{2007}{-.7}{0}One
\item \placetext{2009}{-.7}{0}Two
\item \placetext{2012}{-.7}{0}Three
\item Four
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a TikZ solution using the infamous `\tikzmark` macro to mark a particular place in the document, and `\PlaceText` to place the text. The `\PlaceText` macro accepts an optional first parameter that can be used to customize the text, as shown in the second two cases below:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The name of the mark passed to `\tikzmark` is arbitrary and has no relation to the text, but the same name that was used to name the mark needs to be passed to the `\PlaceText` macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\PlaceText}[4][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node [anchor=base, #1] at ($(#2) + (#3)$) {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
Here's what I want:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \tikzmark{First} One
  \item \tikzmark{Second} Two
  \item \tikzmark{Third} Three
\end{itemize}

\PlaceText{-0.85cm,0.0cm}{First}{2007}
\PlaceText[text=black, fill=red!30, draw=black, dashed]{-0.85cm,0.0cm}{Second}{2009}
\PlaceText[text=blue, fill=yellow]{-0.85cm,0.0cm}{Third}{2012}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not that it's a big deal, but I just realized after the recent spate of `\tikzmark` answers that you should be using `\coordinate` rather than `\node`.  Because you are making a coordinate.

Comment: @RyanReich: Hmmm...Yes, the `\tikzmark` should use `\coordinate`. Good point...  I think it is left over since sometimes there were cases where `\tikzmark` had to measure the width of the node for later use.  I will try to go thru these this weekend and fix that.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the result without tikz and without picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\newcommand\placetext[2][-0.5cm]{\hspace*{#1}\llap{\colorbox{yellow}{#2}}\hspace*{-#1}} 
\begin{document}

Here's what I want:

\begin{itemize}
\item \placetext{2007}One 
\item \placetext{2009}Two 
\item \placetext{2012}Three 
\item Four
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's possible to get some refinements with `\raisebox` if you want to use another argument for a vertical adjustment.

Another idea from egreg is to define `\placetext` with a `\makebox`

```
\newcommand\placetext[2][0.5cm]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\colorbox{yellow}{#2}\hspace{#1}}}
```

Comment: Why not `\makebox[0pt][r]{#2\hspace{#1}}`?

Comment: @egreg yes it's possible but what is the advantage ?

Comment: The code is more compact and manageable. Also `\makebox` is "color safe", while `\llap` isn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "color safe" ? I updated my example and I added a color.

Comment: Try `\color` instead of `\colorbox`. It *might* work, but the color declaration could also spill out.

Comment: @egreg Interesting to know, thank you for the information.