# How to draw an arrow to a specified position in a frame and write some notes on the another end of arrow?

Tags: beamer, arrows, tikz-arrows

I would like to make an arrow and write some notes as shown below
[image]

I tried with the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\author{Author}
\title{Presentation title}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\ft{MATERIAL IN THE UNIVERSE}
\framesubtitle{Simulations need to account for the full cosmic matter-energy content}
\begin{block}{Main ingredients of the Universe:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dark Energy \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ expansion, $a(t)$
\item Dark Matter \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ collisionless fluid, interacting \\ \hspace{68 mm} via gravity
\item Baryonic Matter (`gas') $\Rightarrow $ \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=green!20,anchor=base] (t1){(magneto)hydrodynamic};},\\ \hspace{68 mm} self-gravity
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item that is actually not enough, we need to include sub-resolution physics (cooling, star formation, feedback processes, ...) and we would like to have radiative transport as well
        \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<3-> (n1) edge [out=0, in=-90] (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

But it is giving me the following error

> ! Undefined control sequence. \beamer@doifinframe ...gas')
>   $\Rightarrow $ \tikz [baseline]{\node [fill=gre... l.185 } The control
>   sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
>   \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the
>   correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
>   forget about whatever was undefined.

How can I solve this? What could be the problem? Is there any another easier method to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use `remember picture` in the options of `n1` and `t1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use remember picture in the options of `n1` and `t1` like

```
\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\author{Author}
\title{Presentation title}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{MATERIAL IN THE UNIVERSE}
\framesubtitle{Simulations need to account for the full cosmic matter-energy content}
\begin{block}{Main ingredients of the Universe:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dark Energy \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ expansion, $a(t)$
\item Dark Matter \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ collisionless fluid, interacting \\ \hspace{68 mm} via gravity
\item Baryonic Matter (`gas') $\Rightarrow $ \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[fill=green!20,anchor=base] (t1){(magneto)hydrodynamic};},\\ \hspace{68 mm} self-gravity
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item that is actually not enough, we need to include sub-resolution physics (cooling, star formation, feedback processes, ...) and we would like to have radiative transport as well
        \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   %% use here too
        \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([yshift=2mm]n1.north) to [out=0, in=0,distance=1in] (t1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\author{Author}
\title{Presentation title}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (#1) {#1};}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{MATERIAL IN THE UNIVERSE}
\framesubtitle{Simulations need to account for the full cosmic matter-energy content}
\begin{block}{Main ingredients of the Universe:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dark Energy \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ expansion, $a(t)$
\item Dark Matter \hspace{16.3 mm} $\Rightarrow $ collisionless fluid, interacting \\ \hspace{68 mm} via gravity
\item Baryonic Matter (`gas') $\Rightarrow $ \tikzmark{t1},\\ \hspace{68 mm} self-gravity
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item that is actually not enough,\tikzmark{n1} we need to include sub-resolution physics (cooling, star formation, feedback processes, ...) and we would like to have radiative transport as well
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        %\path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([yshift=3mm]n1) to ++(0,3mm) to [out=0, in=0,distance=2.5in] (t1);
   \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([yshift=3mm]n1) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may better use `tikzmark` for defining `n1` and `t1` and also use `to` instead of `edge`. `edge` is a monster with lot of powers and you can expect trouble sometimes with monsters ;-)

Comment: @RSJohn: Use `remember picture` in `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path[draw=magenta,....` also, which I forgot earlier.

Comment: With this example, the tikzpicture doesn't just add an arrow, but it also adds spurious blank space where it is put (here, at the bottom of the block). For instance, remove the `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` part, and see how the position of the text is modified. How can one eliminate this space?

Comment: Replying to my own comment: the picture needs to be put in an existing paragraph. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

First, as already said, `remember picture` needs to be used in `n1` and `t1` too, but this can be done globally with:

```
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
```

Moreover, the picture with the arrow needs to be part of a paragraph, as [said in answer to *Tikzpicture with overlay takes up space*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/tikzpicture-with-overlay-takes-up-space/23042#23042). Here's an example with various correct and incorrect solutions:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

% Tests of TikZ pictures with remember picture + overlay
% under Debian/unstable on 2016-06-14 (TeX Live 2016).

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

%%% Frame without the arrow (expected layout)

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};

\end{frame}

%%% Frame with an arrow - correct (TikZ picture part of a paragraph)

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};
\tikz[overlay]{\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);}%

\end{frame}

%%% Frame with an arrow - correct (TikZ picture part of a paragraph)

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

\tikz[overlay]{\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);}%
Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};

\end{frame}

%%% Frame with an arrow - incorrect due to picture not in a paragraph
%%% The picture takes some space, slightly moving text upwards.

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};

\tikz[overlay]{\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);}%

\end{frame}

%%% Frame with an arrow - also incorrect: the \makebox(0,0) does not help
%%% Same problem.

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};

\makebox(0,0){\tikz[overlay]{\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);}}%

\end{frame}

%%% Frame with an arrow - also incorrect due to picture not in a paragraph
%%% The space taken by the picture is now between the two lines of text.

\begin{frame}

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

\makebox(0,0){\tikz[overlay]{\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);}}%

Text \tikz[baseline] \node[coordinate] (t1) {};

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```