# point to a table cell in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, arrows

I have created the following table in beamer.
I wish to point to the totals at the bottom of the table, using an arrow.
I also wish to have a label at the arrow's tail.
The arrows need to appear once the table and its contents have been displayed.

```
 \begin{document}{beamer}
 \begin{frame}{The number of journeys by bees on 29th October}
   \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}}
   \textcolor{blue}{Score $(x)$} & \textcolor{magenta}{Frequency $(f)$}  & $f\times x$ \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$0$} & \textcolor{magenta}{$100$}& $0 \times 100=0$  \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$1$}& \textcolor{magenta}{$25$} & $1 \times 25=25$ \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$2$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$75$}  & $150$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$3$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$400$}  & $1200$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$4$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$150$}  & $600$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$5$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$80$}  & $400$  \\
   \rowcolor{orange}  Total  & $830$  & $2375$   \\
   \end{tabular}

  \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
   \item How many bees are there in total?
   \item What is the total number of journeys that the bees made?
  \end{itemize}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Annotating Tables With Tikz; Adding Arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167000/134144) and [Beamer: how to point an arrow to a specific position and then add some text at that position?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390523/134144) could be interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I interpret your question correctly. (BTW, your document didn't compile, so I had to fix the preamble.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array,colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{The number of journeys by bees on 29th October}
   \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}c!{\vrule}}
   \textcolor{blue}{Score $(x)$} & \textcolor{magenta}{Frequency $(f)$}  & $f\times x$ \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$0$} & \textcolor{magenta}{$100$}& $0 \times 100=0$  \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$1$}& \textcolor{magenta}{$25$} & $1 \times 25=25$ \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$2$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$75$}  & $150$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$3$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$400$}  & $1200$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$4$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$150$}  & $600$   \\
   \textcolor{blue}{$5$}  & \textcolor{magenta}{$80$}  & $400$  \\
   \rowcolor{orange}  Total  & $\tikzmarknode{A}{830}$  & $\tikzmarknode{B}{2375}$   \\
   \end{tabular}
\only<1>{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-,thick] (A.north east) -- ++ (4,2) node[right]{tail};
\draw[latex-,thick] (B.north east) -- ++ (2,1) node[right]{tail};
\end{tikzpicture}}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
   \item How many bees are there in total?
   \item What is the total number of journeys that the bees made?
  \end{itemize}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]