# Arrow between two itemizes in two columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, tikz-arrows

I'm doing a beamer presentation and I have two columns with items, and I would like to draw an arrow conecting two items in the different columns. I'm not familiar with Tikz, son I having some problems. How can I do it ?

A minimal preamble here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}

\column{.5\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
    \item element A
    \item element B
    \item element C
    \item element D
    \item element E
\end{itemize}

\column{.5\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
     \item element F
     \item element G
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to draw an arrow between elements B and F.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199218/how-to-draw-an-arrow-to-a-specified-position-in-a-frame-and-write-some-notes-on could help, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/how-can-i-draw-arrows-between-words-in-linguistic-examples

Comment: It worked, but I'm trying to add text on the line and it does not compile. I'm using \path[draw=red,thick,->]<3-> (node_elementB) -- (node_elementF), but adding {text} produces an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

by use of `tikzmark` library :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, quotes, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\tikzset{box/.style={inner xsep=0pt}}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item element A
    \item element B\tikzmark{b}
    \item element C
    \item element D
    \item element E
\end{itemize}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
     \item \tikzmark{f}element F
     \item element G
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[very thick, -Stealth]         ($({pic cs:b})+(1ex,1ex)$)
        to [bend left, sloped, "text"]  ($({pic cs:f})+(1ex,+1em)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```